# javascript Heap out of memory in one module file

Tags: angular

my project has only one module file that's why I think this error occurs. but now what should I do

I tried to create every component has a module file

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem when building and serving Angular applications.

The node process that runs on `ng build` and `ng serve` is limited to 512MB RAM on 32bit systems and 1GB RAM on 64bit systems.

Both processes (serve and build) often requires a lot more than that, so you can fix this by executing the build/serve tasks directly from node_modules, and passing a `max_old_space_size` parameter along that determines how much RAM you will give the process.

So running `ng serve` and dedicating 4GB of memory to the process becomes

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

And runnning `ng build` while dedicating 4GB of memory is

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build
```

You can add these commands as scripts in your `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build",
  }
  ...
}
```